# android - stopping sound when the application goes to background

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I use the following code to stop the music that plays in loop in the app background when the app goes to background, it works on the emulator, not so much on the phone. Even when I exit the app the sound still plays, anyone got a solution for that? I'd be very thankful

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
Context context = getApplicationContext();
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
  ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
  if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
      MusicManager.getInstance().stopMusic();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU LEFT YOUR APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

MusicManager:

```
public class MusicManager {
MediaPlayer mp = null;
private static MusicManager refrence = null;

public static MusicManager getInstance(){
if(refrence==null){
    refrence = new MusicManager();
}
return refrence;
}
public void initializeMediaPlayer(Context context, int musicID){ 
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.rock);
 mp.setLooping(true);   
 try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void playMusic(){
mp.start();
}
public void stopMusic(){
    if (mp != null) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
}

}
}
```

Main:

```
MusicManager.getInstance().initializeMediaPlayer(this, R.raw.rock);
MusicManager.getInstance().playMusic();
```

Comment: Are you seeing the Toast?

Comment: No I'm not, however the tasks permission does appear during installation, I'm testing on a Galaxy S4

Comment: How did you start playing the music?

Comment: if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) , is this evaluating to true ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use activitylifecyclecallbacks to check whether app is foreground or background. It was added in api level 14.
You may use the following code

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 public class MYLifeCycleHandler implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks 
 {
  private static int resumed;
  private static int paused;
  private static int started;
  private static int stopped;

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) 
  {
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity)
  {
    ++resumed;
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity)
  {
    ++paused;
  }   

  @Override
  public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    ++started;        
    if(started > stopped)
    {
    //start music player if not already running
    MusicManager.getInstance().playMusic();
    }
   }

  public boolean isApplicationInForeground() 
  {
    return resumed > paused;
  }
  @Override
  public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    ++stopped;
    //if application in background
    if(stopped == started)
    {
        //stop music player if running
       MusicManager.getInstance().stopMusic();
    }
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)       
   {        
   }
  }
```

You should register for callbacks as follows

```
getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MPLifeCycleHandler());
```

Ideally register in the onCreate of your first activity

Comment: Why the variable TAG, also should Application app_ be private ? I'm getting a warning variable is not used.

Comment: In addition when I register for callbacks in first activity a get error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplication() from the type Activity"

Comment: I've updated the code. I had pasted the code I was using so there were some variables not required for your application and if your registering in the onCreate method  of an activity then you wont get that error. Can you put your code?

Comment: now when i register i Get error in the bit "activity.getApplication()", it says that activity cannot be resolved

Comment: can you post some code so that I can check whats wrong?

Comment: are you doing activity.getApplication()? Just getApplication() should work fine

Comment: i posted the code, still getting an error with getApplication()

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I had removed that constructor with with application as parameter. Now you should register as follows.                                                             getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MPLifeCycleHandler());

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ImageView startB;
Bitmap b = null;
int keyCode = 0;
boolean onKeyDown = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MYLifeCycleHandler(getApplication())); // New error:the constructor MYLifeCycleHandler is undefined
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    /* adapt the image to the size of the display */
    Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point p = new Point();
    d.getSize(p);
    b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.screen1),//b
            p.x, p.y, true);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);
    rl.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b));

    ImageView startB = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
    MusicManager.getInstance().initializeMediaPlayer(this, R.raw.rock);
    MusicManager.getInstance().playMusic();

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        onKeyDown = true;
    }

     startB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutPlace2.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
public void onHomePressed(){
    if (onKeyDown = true){
        AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
}
/*@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}*/

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
      ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
      if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
          MusicManager.getInstance().stopMusic();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU LEFT YOUR APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
      }
    }
    if (b != null){
        b.recycle();
        b = null;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    MusicManager.getInstance().playMusic();
}
}
```

MYLifeCycleHadler:

Exactly as in your updated post